# How to ignore a folder during build in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building react native application for android, ios and TV platform. I have a folder structure like below:

[image: Folder_Structure]

When I build for mobile, I want to ignore compiling and packing the tablet&tv files into android.bundle.js and same for iOS.

Let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: can you post the webpack config you are using?

Comment: Hi @Harish, I'm not using webpack in the project. This is react native

Comment: @ManojPrabhakar I am also looking for the same. Did you able to manage to get it work?